# Why SplPriorityQueue class is a queue (conceptual)

Tags: php, spl

Basically `SplPriorityQueue` class is a heap using `max heap` algoritm.

I don't understand why in documentation is supposed to be a `prioritized queue`, because a `queue` is a **FIFO** collection (first in, first out) - but because `SplPriorityQueue` it depend of `priority variable` for comparison function, why it is a queue ?

Why the class is not just a `SplPriorityCollection` ?!

-> [SplPriorityQueue documentation](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.splpriorityqueue.php)

---

Inspired by **Mark Baker** comment i tested the behaviour of compare function when the priority is the same for all items and it turned out that with the same priority the collection is not a **FIFO**

```
$objPQ = new SplPriorityQueue(); 

$objPQ->insert('A', 1); 
$objPQ->insert('B', 1); 
$objPQ->insert('C', 1); 
$objPQ->insert('D', 1); 
$objPQ->insert('E', 1); 
$objPQ->insert('F', 1);
$objPQ->insert('G', 1);


foreach($objPQ as $val) {
    echo $val . "\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
A G F E D C B
```

Comment: Because (unless you specify different priorities) it is FIFO.... and in most cases you will specify the same priority for everything... the difference between a PriorityQueue and a Queue is that you ___have the option___ to prioritise entries so that some ___can___ be processed before others

Comment: Thx. I tested, and with the same priority doesn't act like a FIFO. View my edited question. It's very good point, and i didn't think this way but it doesn't apply.

Comment: In that case, you may have found a bug: for a queue, behaviour should be as I've described.... otherwise you might as well just use an splheap

Comment: see the user-contributed note [here](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/splpriorityqueue.compare.php) though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Basically `SplPriorityQueue` class is a heap using `max heap` algoritm [sic].

The fact that a heap is used is an *implementation detail*, using a heap is not a requirement. The priority queue data structure is not unique to PHP either (not that anyone said it is!). Hopefully the following short citation from Wikipedia will help:

> While priority queues are often implemented with heaps, they are conceptually distinct from heaps. A priority queue is an abstract concept like "a list" or "a map"; just as a list can be implemented with a linked list or an array, a priority queue can be implemented with a heap or a variety of other methods such as an unordered array.
>
> – http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

---

The same source also has the following to say:

> If two elements have the same priority, they are served according to their order in the queue

This is contrary to the SplPriorityQueue's author's comments in a PHP bug report ([[Won't Fix] Bug #53710   Data registered with equal priority not returned in expected order](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53710)) describing the iteration (mis)behaviour with equal priority values.

> There is no such guarantee. The only guarantee that you'll get from 
>   SplPriorityQueue is that you won't get an element out of order. Elements with the 
>   same priority are extracted in arbitrary order, the rest is implementation 
>   dependant.

The author of the above bug report went on to write up a blog post, [Taming SplPriorityQueue](http://mwop.net/blog/253-Taming-SplPriorityQueue.html), which hits on enforcing a predictable queue order using the following technique:

```
namespace Foo;

class SplPriorityQueue extends \SplPriorityQueue
{
    protected $queueOrder = PHP_INT_MAX;

    public function insert($datum, $priority)
    {
        if (is_int($priority)) {
            $priority = array($priority, $this->queueOrder--);
        }
        parent::insert($datum, $priority);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. Remarkable what a documented response you gave.

Comment: In short terms what i understand after reading the documentation (wikipedia, manual, bug-report) is that a `Priority queue` is a distinct abstract concept different from the `Queue`. Correct my if  i'm wrong.

Comment: Just for clarification, what does $priority = array($priority, $this->queueOrder--); do?

Answer (score 3):

SPLPriorityQueue appears to act more like a Heap than a Queue, the FIFO aspect that should be used for it to be a queue isn't applied

However, FIFO can be restored by modifying the insert to adjust the value used in the comparison function

```
class PQtest extends SplPriorityQueue 
{ 
    protected $serial = PHP_INT_MAX;

    public function insert($value, $priority) {
        parent::insert($value, array($priority, $this->serial--));
    }

    public function compare($priority1, $priority2) 
    { 
        if ($priority1 === $priority2) return 0; 
        return $priority1 < $priority2 ? -1 : 1; 
    } 
} 

$objPQ = new PQtest(); 

$objPQ->insert('A',1); 
$objPQ->insert('B',1); 
$objPQ->insert('C',1); 
$objPQ->insert('D',1); 
$objPQ->insert('E',1); 
$objPQ->insert('F',1); 

echo "COUNT->".$objPQ->count().PHP_EOL; 

//mode of extraction 
$objPQ->setExtractFlags(PQtest::EXTR_BOTH); 

//Go to TOP 
$objPQ->top(); 

while($objPQ->valid()){ 
    print_r($objPQ->current()); 
    echo PHP_EOL; 
    $objPQ->next(); 
}
```

Comment: Txh. Smart way to enforce FIFO principle overriding insert method. +1